# Ebean: How to create Iterator or Future from SqlQuery

Tags: java, ebean

I want to create Iterator or Future from SqlQuery because if loading all SqlRows, causing out of memory exceptions.
I cant use `EbeanServer.find()`, so use SqlQuery.
Query has `findIterate` and `findFutureList` but SqlQuery don't have.

Comment: As a side note: query.findEach() and query.findEachWhile() are usually preferred over query.findIterate() as they guarantee the resources (ResultSet etc) are closed properly where as with findIterate() developers have to remember to close the QueryIterator in a finally block.

Answer (score 1):

Correct, SqlQuery does not have findIterate() or findEach() ... but it does have a similar mechanism.

You instead use setListener.

```
SqlQuery sqlQuery = Ebean.createSqlQuery("select * from o_order");
sqlQuery.setListener(new SqlQueryListener() {
  @Override
  public void process(SqlRow bean) {
    // process 1 row at a time to avoid OOM with large queries
    System.out.println("process row "+bean);
  }
});
// returns an empty list
sqlQuery.findList();
```

I'll log an enhancement to add findEach(), findEachWhile() to SqlQuery which would ultimately replace this setListener() approach.

This is logged as https://github.com/ebean-orm/avaje-ebeanorm/issues/675

**UPDATE:**

In version 7.9.1 you would do something like:

```
SqlQuery sqlQuery = Ebean.createSqlQuery("select * from o_order");
sqlQuery.findEach(new QueryEachConsumer<SqlRow>() {
  @Override
  public void accept(SqlRow row) {
    // process row
  }
});
```

And there is also the findEachWhile() equivalent.